# what is a double in rspec ? I am writing a test and can't find information on 'double'- line 15 below:

Tags: rspec

> this is the Comment-rspec, it works, but I don't understand what the double does.  my research has returned nothing.

require 'rails_helper'

```
 describe Comment do

   include TestFactories

   describe "after_create" do

 before do
   @post = associated_post
   @user = authenticated_user
   @comment = Comment.new(body: 'My comment', post: @post, user_id: 10000)
 end

 it "sends an email to users who have favorited the post" do
   @user.favorites.where(post: @post).create

    allow( FavoriteMailer )
     .to receive(:new_comment)
     .with(@user, @post, @comment)
     .and_return( double(deliver_now: true) )

   @comment.save
 end

 it "does not send emails to users who haven't" do
   expect( FavoriteMailer )
     .not_to receive(:new_comment)

   @comment.save
 end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double is the basic mocking object in RSpec, as described in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs. In your case, it's providing an implementation of the `deliver_now` method. Your first `it` block isn't really testing anything, though, as there are no assertions within in it.